# Entity Framework SQL Server increments an Id Key out of order if previous values are available

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, key, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 website and it has a SQL Server DB that contains its posts. On each post there is a `Next` and `Previous` button. These buttons are calculated from `databaseContext.Post.Count()` plus or minus 1 and (if item = zero don't display `Previous`, and the other way round.) However due to some `Posts` being deleted there are some spots in between that are null. This doesn't bother me except now for some reason the DB has been adding new entries to these empty spots, so the `Count()` vs what is actualy their is off and this causes the highest value's next to point to a higher value than what actually exists (since it is over the total count, keep in mind that even its Id is over the total count.)

I know I can programmatically check for this type of issue however I was wondering if there a way to change how the Id keys are created?

Comment: Your question is a little confusing.  Are you saying that if you have records 1,2,3 and delete 2, the db will create another 2 rather than creating a 4?

Comment: @AnnL. Kind of, except it seems to require more than 1 being removed. Say I have records 1 to 10,000 then say 500 missing then 10,501 to 14,000; for some reason at some point is starts adding records to 10,001++ instead of 14,001. (At some point we had a bot post a bunch of spam and had to remove a large amount of posts.)

Comment: A quick Google search didn't find me anything, but I would previously have bet a small amount of money that SQL Server didn't backfill gaps in sequence when populating identity columns.  If it does, then there's no way to get the true order in which records were added.  I would look to EF before SQL Server as the culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assuming that a generated ID will be dense monotonous, with no gaps. This is incorrect assumption. There will always be gaps in the generated IDs. You can never assume that counting the records will give you valid IDs. If you want a dense, monotonous row number use the dedicated [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function, but leveraging this for navigation is problematic.